# Quarto revealjs presentation does not scroll down in browser

Tags: r, yaml, quarto, scrollable, presentation

I am trying to prepare lecture slides with quarto in revealjs format (previously used xaringan with great results).

When I open the rendered html with any browser (Firebox, Chrome, Edge), I cannot scroll down to the content that is at the bottom.  I have tried `scrollable: true` and in YAML and `{.scrollable}` next to slide headings; they don't work.  The example below has an R code that produces a regression table but even if the slide consists only of text, it will not scroll down.

This makes quarto unusable for my lectures, but I wish to switch to quarto for everything as soon as I can, so any help is appreciate.

YAML:

```
title: "Regression"
author: "Me"
format:
  revealjs: 
    theme: dark
    incremental: true
    scrollable: true
    transition: slide
execute:
  echo: true
editor: visual
```

Example Slide:

````
# Preparation

- `jtools` is just a quick way to produce regression analyses and plots
- dataset is from base R
- We have a significant interaction

. . . 

```{r}
library(jtools) # for summ()
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
fiti <- lm(Income ~ Illiteracy * Murder + `HS Grad`, data = states)
summ(fiti)
````

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. I tried a couple of things including installing the pre-release version of quarto, trying out extensions and adjusting different flags. What ended up restoring the scrolling was setting my

```
format:
  revealjs:
    slide-level: 1
```

but that is not really any good as I will just have these enormously long slide. I don't think this is the intended functionality. You should probably file a bug report on (GitHub)[https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto/issues]

Answer (score 0):

As explained in Quarto doc (https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/#creating-slides)

Default setting to create slides are:

- `#`  for sections slides
- `##` for normal slides

Sections slides are meant to be a title and a subtitle, and are by default centered.

Normal slides are for content, and not centered by default.

`scrollable: true` will apply overflow on non-center slides only

```css
  .reveal .slide:not(.center) {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

For scrollable to work, `height: 100%` is required, which is not set for slide with `.center` class. And it does not seem good practice to allow scroll on section slides that are centered.

So you need to put your content in the normal slide not a section slide

````markdown
---
title: "Regression"
author: "Me"
format:
  revealjs: 
    theme: dark
    incremental: true
    scrollable: true
    transition: slide
execute:
  echo: true
editor: visual
---

## Preparation

- `jtools` is just a quick way to produce regression analyses and plots
- dataset is from base R
- We have a significant interaction

. . . 


```{r}
library(jtools) # for summ()
states <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
fiti <- lm(Income ~ Illiteracy * Murder + `HS Grad`, data = states)
summ(fiti)
```
````

In @agdamsbo answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77129464/3436535), setting `slide-level: 1` makes it works, because normal slides are now `#` and no more section slide possible.

Hope it helps clarifies.

If this behavior does not seem like a good one, please do open a discussion on Quarto repo so that we can discuss as feature request an evolution of this.